# Boolean expression evaluation with a given context

Tags: evaluation, boolean-expression

What are some algorithms for evaluating a boolean expression given some context taken as true?

For example take the expression
    A & (B || C) || (E && F)
and we know that the expression
    B || F
is true. What is an algorithm for creating a new expression?

This is easy to do for certain contexts, single predicates or a series of them anded together.  But I'm not sure about a general procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Stop coding, close compiler and open book of boolean algebra.

Comment: I don't have one handy. I searched google for a while and couldn't find anything even referencing this topic.